# How do I add styling to a javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color

I have a page with a data grid and when I print it i want only the data grid to be printed. On clicking print all other elements in the page (left nav, header, footer etc) are removed and only the necessary part(which is in a div called printdiv) is displayed. But unfortunately I can't get it to display the background i want. Please Help!!!
I need the background to be white, but instead it is grey, which is the background for the rest of the site, Is there a way I can change the background for the form alone?

This is the javascript I'm using

```
            <div id="printDiv" >

                <div id="maincontent-right-wrapper">
                    <div class="page-heading">
                        <spring:message
                            code="rmp.store_performance_yearly.page_header.store_performance_yearly" />
                    </div>

                    <!--shop starts-->
                    <div class="shop-promoter-wrapper">
                        <div class="shop-promoter-inner">

                            <ul>
                                <li><spring:message
                                        code="rmp.store_performance_yearly.label.store" /></li>
                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                <li><form:select path="storeid">
                                        <form:options items="${StoreList}" itemValue="storeId"
                                            itemLabel="storeName" />
                                    </form:select></li>
                                <li><img src="../static/images/spacer.gif" width="26"
                                    height="1" /></li>

                                <li><spring:message
                                        code="rmp.store_performance_yearly.label.year" /></li>
                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                <li><form:select path="year">
                                        <form:options items="${YearList}" />
                                    </form:select></li>

                                <li>&nbsp;</li>
                                <li><a href="#" onclick="callGo(1)">
                                        <div class="button-wrapper">
                                            <div class="button-left">&nbsp;</div>
                                            <div class="button-middle">
                                                <spring:message
                                                    code="rmp.store_performance_yearly.button.go" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="button-right">&nbsp;</div>
                                        </div>
                                </a></li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: More information please. What have you tried? What does your current code look like? etc.

Comment: Code is worth a thousand words...

Comment: This is how am calling it:
<a onclick="showConfirm('printDiv')">
     <div class="button-wrapper">
      <div class="button-left">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="button-middle">
       <spring:message code="rmp.store_performance_yearly.button.print"/>
      </div>
      <div class="button-right">&nbsp;</div>
     </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is worth a thousand words, but FYI browsers usually don't print backgrounds, and it's a user-controlled setting whether they do. So your best bet is to not a use a background (there's a reason browsers don't print them, the results tend not to be very good) or make whatever background you want to have an actual element on the page, behind the div (lower in the Z order).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the css. all you have to do is adding another css declaration for printing like this:

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

so you can use classes like:

```
.style1 {display: none;}
```

in your print.css file for every element you dont want to print

Comment: you mean `.noPrint { display:none}` and give `class="noPrint"` to the object you want to not print

Comment: no I don't mean that. I mean using `display: none` in `print.css` file so they won't be displayed when printing. anyway i have edited my answer so that the `style` keyword does not confuse

Comment: Yes you did mean that. You changed your answer to be exactly what I said. .noPrint in the print.css and the noPrint class on the object